# Strange shading in smooth mode

Tags: 3d-view

Smooth mode has strange patches on a flat surface. Normals are all facing outwards. Turning off subsurf fixes the problem but isn't ideal. Any ideas how to fix this?
[image: Smooth mode has strange patches on a flat surface]

Comment: Try recalculating the normals

Comment: maybe you have inner faces?

Comment: @NascentSpace I've tried that, but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @moonboots I've tried selecting innner faces, but there aren't any.

Comment: Merge by distance?

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Try going into vertex properties and check Smooth Normals and play around with the angle limit.